# What is a way to create a fluent interface in C++ that allows extension of the fluent interface?

Tags: c++

Here is an example of a fluent interface in C++:

```
struct Object {
    Object& add(std::string value) { values.insert(value); return *this; }
    std::set<std::string> values;
};
```

And here is an example of using it:

```
Object().add("1").add("2");
```

I would like to extend the fluent interface without modifying the original class, for example with this function:

```
Object& multipleAdd(Object& object, int value1, int value2) {
   return object.add(value1).add(value2);
}
```

This function can be called like this:

```
multipleAdd(Object().add("1").add("2"), "3", "4");
```

But not like this:

```
multipleAdd(Object(), "3", "4");
```

I plan to change the fluent interface to this:

```
struct Object {
    Object& add(std::string value) { values.insert(value); return *this; }
    Object& self() { return *this; } // <--- New function
    std::set<std::string> values;
};
```

So that it can be used like this:

```
multipleAdd(Object().self(), "3, "4");
```

Is there anything unsafe about this? Is there a better way?

Comment: Where will the object live after the function has returned?

Comment: It would be copied to someplace safe. This is the same as would be required in a standard method chaining usage like `Object().add("1").add("2");`.

Comment: If it is not immediately copied into a variable after the function returns (same line) it is definitely unsafe. Otherwise, I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks. I think that is a potential downfall in almost any fluent interface implementation in C++. I wonder how this approach compares to other approaches of implementing fluent interfaces in C++.

Comment: You can declare the variable before the function call and then pass a reference to it. You could also use C++11 move semantics but I'm not an expert on those.

Comment: Yes, but that would eliminate one of the benefits of using a fluent interface - that the potential for accidental reuse of the variable is eliminated.

Comment: Why not simply create the Object inside the function and not outside, and only pass the extra parameters?

Comment: @NeilKirk Then it function can't be used in a chain except at the start of the chain - it won't be fluent anymore.